# Fine Uploader with Webpack & ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, fine-uploader

I am attempting to integrate fine-uploader with a React/ES6 application that is bundled via Webpack. Looking for guidance on how to include fine-uploader with this stack.

In my `webpack.config.js` I have set an alias for Fine Uploader like so:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      'fine-uploader': path.resolve('node_modules/fine-uploader/s3.fine-uploader')
    }
}
```

And in my React component I have the following:

```
import React from 'react'

import 'fine-uploader'

export default () => {
  return <h1>Fine Uploader</h1>
}
```

Webpack barks at me though:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /Users/mfeltner/code/yden/foo/node_modules/fine-uploader/s3.fine-uploader in /Users/mfeltner/code/yden/foo/static/common/containers/fine-uploader
 @ ./static/common/containers/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.jsx 11:20-44
```

I'm fairly sure I need to shim the fine-uploader javascript somehow since it behaves the old school way by attaching itself to `window.qq`, and I'd imagine this doesn't play well with module loaders.

Comment: This is now much easier in Fine Uploader 5.8.0. More details at http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/modules.html.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out!

First, I had to install the [`exports-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exports-loader) for webpack. This loader will shim non-CommonJS/UMD/AMD bundles so you can `require` or `import` them ([read more here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#exporting)). Then I had to edit my `webpack.config.js` to shim the `qq` namespace for the type of Fine Uploader I am using (S3 in this case):

**`webpack.config.js`**:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /s3\.fine-uploader\.js/,
            loader: 'exports?qq'
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I am able to `import` the `qq` object from Fine Uploader and access it just as I would normally, except it's not on the global namespace. Win!

Note that I had to include a `ref` to the React-rendered DOM element so Fine Uploader knew where to attach itself. Also, note the use of `componentDidMount` to ensure the element *has* been rendered by React.

**`fine-uploader.jsx`**:

```
import React from 'react'

import qq from 'fine-uploader/s3.fine-uploader'

class FU extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    const fu = new qq.s3.FineUploaderBasic({
      button: this.refs.fu
    })
  }

  render () {
    return <div ref='fu'>Upload!</div>
  }
}

export default FU
```

I'll probably have more questions as I try and integrate this library with React and the modern Javascript ecosystem.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working for me, could you extend on your answer? I'm still not finding the qq variable in my modules. no thats a lie. I find the qq variable but its just an empty object.. `qq.s3 is undefined`

Comment: specifiying the filename as well worked for me `import qq from 'fine-uploader/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.js'`.  It took longer than i care to admit to figure that out...

Comment: @Pascal Maybe if you opened a new question and shared your code I'd be able to take a look, otherwise I'll just be guessing.

Comment: yes it is true that as of current it would be `import qq from 'fine-uploader/s3.fine-uploader/s3.fine-uploader.js'` or one of the variants like `import qq from 'fine-uploader/all.fine-uploader/all.fine-uploader.js'`. This is because it is an improperly packaged npm distro (has no enclosed package.json or an entry file named index.js). Currently using `5.7.1` with `Node 5.9.x` with `webpack 1.13.0` and `exports-loader 0.6.3`.

Comment: @VictoriaFrench you are right, Fine Uploader was initially made years before CommonJS existed (the dark days of JS), and we have to work around that. Sorry that it is an inconvenience. 

I'm not sure what you all are doing differently since I do not have to specify the filename. Are you sure you have a webpack alias setup (see my initial question)?

Comment: @VictoriaFrench There _is_ a package.json included in the package downloaded from npm. There is no index.js as this would not make much sense in the context of Fine Uploader, since there is not a single entry-point for all users. Some may elect to use the S3 version, others may elect to use the azure, and still others may pick the traditional uploader. These _could_ be registered as separate npm packages, and this is certainly something to consider for the future.

Answer (score 2):

Just updated to NPM release 5.9.0 and can see they now export modules.  This means you can import it into your component without having to use the exports loader in webpack.

`import qq from 'fine-uploader/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.js';`

also works with

`import qq from 'fine-uploader/lib/traditional';`

for the s3 loader use

`import qq from 'fine-uploader/lib/s3';`

Comment: You can import the traditional library much easier: `import qq from 'fine-uploader'`. The docs cover all of this and more in [the imports feature page](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/modules.html).