# How to use Fine-Uploader with Browserify?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I'm trying to use `Fine-Uploader` with `Browserify` and can't manage to make it work.

So far I've tried two things with the **5.4.1** and **5.7.1** versions:

- Using the global `qq` variable but I got an
  `Uncaught ReferenceError: qq is not defined(…)` error,
- Using `require('file-uploader')` which resulted in an `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'fine-uploader'(…)` error

Here is the content of my `package.json`:

```
"browser": {
    "fine-uploader": "./node_modules/fine-uploader/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.js",
    ...
},
"browserify-shim": {
    "fine-uploader": "qq",
    ...
},
"dependencies": {
    "fine-uploader": "^5.7.1",
    ...
}
```

I've looked on the GitHub repository. Some issues where similar to my problem yet no solution was given (except the fact that the `require` feature will be available in the **6.x** version)

Can you help me figuring out how to use the `Fine-Uploader` ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't use browserify so I can't give you any specific help with that, but a similar question was opened and answered recently - it deals with using Fine Uploader in a modularized project with WebPack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185540/fine-uploader-with-webpack-es6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe your `browserify-shim` options are incorrect simply because that's the only thing different (AFAIK) between your setup and mine. I was able to get it working with the following:

My `package.json`:

```js
"dependencies": {
  "fine-uploader": "5.7.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "browserify": "13.0.0",
  "browserify-shim": "3.8.12"
},
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
  "browserify-shim"
  ]
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "./node_modules/fine-uploader/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.js": "qq"
},
"browser": {
  "fine-uploader": "./node_modules/fine-uploader/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.js"
}
```

My `index.js`:

```js
var fineuploader = require('fine-uploader')

document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  var fu = new fineuploader.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('fu')
  })

}, false );
```

My `index.html`:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
        <!-- add fine-uploader template here -->
    </script>
    <div id="fu"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am then able to build my bundle with: `browserify . -d -o bundle.js` and can see the uploader on the DOM when I load my `index.html` in a browser.

Comment: The `"browserify": { "transform": ["browserify-shim"] }` did the trick. Thing is, it broke the `vendors`modules of the project.. So I put the FineUploader in the  `vendors`and everything worked. Thanks for your help.