# How to use Fine Uploader in React js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, fine-uploader

Hi i am newbie to Reactjs. i am using fineuploader to upload files to the server.i want to create a FineUploader Component ,so that i can use it where ever i want.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "fine-uploader": "^5.7.1",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: [
       './Components/Main.js'
    ],
    output:{
        path:__dirname,
        filename:'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
          'fine-uploader': path.resolve('node_modules/fine-uploader/fine-uploader')
        }
    },
    module:{
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /fine-uploader\.js/,
                loader: 'exports?qq'
            }
        ],
        loaders:[{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude:/node_modules/,
            loader:'babel',
            query:{
              presets: ['react']
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

**FineUploader.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import qq from 'fine-uploader/fine-uploader';

class FineUploader extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    const fu = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({
      button: this.refs.fu
    })
  }

  render () {
    return <div ref='fu'>Upload!</div>
  }
}

export default FineUploader;
```

**Main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import FineUploader from './FineUploader.js';

var MainContent = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return (
           <div>
             <FineUploader />
           </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<MainContent />,document.getElementById('container'));
```

When i run the Application i am getting the below error
**uncaught TypeError: _fineUploader2.default.FineUploaderBasic is not a constructor**

i dint no what i am doing wrong ,Plz somebody guide me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fine Uploader with Webpack & ES6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185540/fine-uploader-with-webpack-es6)

Comment: React Fine Uploader just released: https://github.com/FineUploader/react-fine-uploader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Fine Uploader with React you will need to create a new uploader instance within the [`componentDidMount` lifecycle method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount).

> Invoked once, only on the client (not on the server), immediately after the initial rendering occurs. At this point in the lifecycle, you can access any refs to your children (e.g., to access the underlying DOM representation).

Fine Uploader needs an actual rendered DOM element for it to attach event handlers, render other DOM elements as children, etc.

Inside of `componentDidMount` we not only know our component has been created, but we also have a DOM element and we can reference it as such using a [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html).

Here's a tiny example component:

```js
class FineUploader extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    const fu = new qq.s3.FineUploaderBasic({
      button: this.refs.fu
    })
  }

  render () {
    return <div ref='fu'>Upload!</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark ,i have added the code like you mentioned but i am getting the below error **Cannot read property 'FineUploaderBasic' of undefined**

Comment: @yasar Did you follow the instructions to set up WebPack in the case I linked to in my comment? Are you referencing the Fine Uploader S3 .js file?

Comment: @yasar also note in my example I used the S3 Fine Uploader. You may need to modify that based on which uploader you are using (azure, s3, all, none, etc.)

Comment: @Ray Nicholus ya i have set up the Webpack properly and i want to use just fine-uploader not s3.fine-uploader.plz see my updated question

Comment: @Mark i have followed all the instructions mentioned in your post,but i am getting the error,i dont know what i am doing wrong.i have updated the question for clear understanding plz guide me

Comment: @yasar By any chance, does it work if you change your import to `import qq from 'fine-uploader/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.js'`?

Comment: @Ray Nicholus if i change my import to import qq from 'fine-uploader/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.js' i am getting the error **Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "fine-uploader/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.js"**

Comment: @yasar scratch that, you shouldn't have to form your input that way anyway. But it looks like you have not installed the webpack exports loader.

Comment: @Ray ,i have installed webpack exports loader and then run werbpack again i am still getting the error.do i need to change anything in the config file

Comment: @yasar I'm working on some changes to Fine Uploader that will allow you to easily import the package of your choice without any additional webpack config. Please follow https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/789 for updates.

Comment: @Ray Thanks you so much that would be great

Comment: @yasar Work is being staged for 5.8.0 in a pull request at https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/pull/1562.

Comment: @yasar 5.8.0 has been released. See the new [modules feature page](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/modules.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Even though my answer is not completely relevant to the asked question but I would recommend the react-fine-uploader library to make your life easier.

https://github.com/FineUploader/react-fine-uploader